# Windows Phone 8 using computer network

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have an app in my Windows Phone 8 and I need to access my network to send the data from my smartphone to my network server.

In Windows Mobile devices, I just needed connect the USB cable on the device and Windows Mobile Device Center connects to my server through the connected computer network.

I've developed the WP client to consume all the data on my server using WCF and what I just need to know is how can I connect my WP 8 using the USB cable (I don't have a wireless hotspot available in my customer) like I did on Windows Mobile earlier.

Best regards

JR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly you want to user your Windows Phone to access your PC's internet connection through USB with out Wi-Fi. IF so.. there is no way of doing this using the USB cable, its not supported. Unless you have wi-fi.

But you can use the Windows Phone Emulator to test your app. It can access your PC's internet connection to connect to the internet. If the phone is a must then you have to turn on your data plan and access internet via that.

Comment: Hi @Kasun, before post this question, I was affraid that this kind of behavior wasn't allowed! Thanks for confirm my fears!! lol